# ajax callback and script tags

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback

So, I've finally figured out an ajax callback does not load the content of a page that is between script tags. I've been trying for ages how to figure out the problem (no jquery expert here). I've read so much and watched videos - use .load instead of .html, use eval, append, put the script in the header....

Anyway, these ways might work too, but the one I'm working with is based on a video I watched:
[http://www.ajaxvideotutorials.com/V11Videos/jquery_evaluateJavascriptInScriptTagsInAjaxResponse.swf][1]

I'm experimenting with simple code, before putting in my big block of code. But why doesn't my code here work? My app is a rails app.

Here is my ajax code, in a scripts.js file. The key line to watch out for is:

```
$(".page-content .testing").find('script') function(){
    alert(eval(value));
}
```

All the other ajax stuff worked fine up to then - this is the code I'm trying to use to show what's between the script tags, in the testing class, which is in page-content

```
$(document).on("ready", function(){

    var ajax_loaded = (function(response) {             

        $(".page-content")

            .html($(response).filter(".page-content"));             

        $(".page-content .ajax").on("click",ajax_load); 

$(".page-content .testing").find('script') function(){
    alert(eval(value));
}
});


var form_submit = (function(e) {                    
    e.preventDefault();                             

    var url = $(this).attr("action");               
    var method = $(this).attr("method");            


    var data = {}                                   
    $(this).find("input, textarea, select").each(function(i){
        var name = $(this).attr("name");            
        var value = $(this).val();                  

        data[name] =value;                          

    }); 

    $.ajax({                                        
        "url": url,                                 
        "type": method,                             
        "data": data,                               
        "success": ajax_loaded,
        "error": function () {alert("bad");}        
    });
});


var history = [];                                   

var current_url_method;                             

var ajax_load = (function(e) {                      
    e.preventDefault();                             


    history.push(this);                             

    var url =$(this).attr("href");                  
    var method = $(this).attr("data-method");       

    if (current_url_method != url + method) {       
        current_url_method = url + method;          

        $.ajax({                                    
            "url": url,                             
            "type": method,                         
            "success": ajax_loaded,                 
        });
     }
});

$("#menu a").on("click",ajax_load);

$("#menu a.main").trigger("click");
$(".search-box form").on("submit", form_submit);
// $("#t_and_c").trigger("click");


});
```

In my show.html.erb file I have:

```
<div class ='page-content'>
<div class = "testing">

<script type="text/javascript">
value=10
</script>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help! Chris

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, if you want elements with either class, they have to be comma separated. If you want elements with both, there can't be a space.

```
$(".page-content,.testing").find('script') function(){
    alert(eval(value));
}
```

or

```
$(".page-content.testing").find('script') function(){
    alert(eval(value));
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yatrix/bBBRa/1/